# How can I add Windows service packs and updates to my Windows XP/Vista install cd/dvd?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

When I install Windows, the first thing I need to do is install the latest service packs and updates.  Can I bake this into the install cd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process is called Slipstreaming.  Here is a [step by step guide for XP](http://www.winsupersite.com/showcase/windowsxp_sp2_slipstream.asp) (bit of a complicated hack).  You can use the [Vista Update Integrator](http://apcmag.com/how_to_slipstream_vista_sp1_into_your_vista_install_dvd.htm) with Windows Vista.  There is the [VLite](http://www.vlite.net/help/slipstream.html) tool for doing it under Vista.  If you want an automated method under XP you can use [NLite](http://www.nliteos.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You mean like [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/)?

Comment: Isn't there an "official" method from Microsoft?

Comment: I think so, but it's waaaaay harder.